# Can I define only one \newcommand or \def to receive different outputs?

Tags: macros

I want to know that if I can get various outputs only one `\newcommand` or `\def` definition. Assume that I have a command like that:

```
\newcommand{\command1}[x]{blablabla}
```

I do not know the syntax is correct above given example (obviously I wanna know how it's syntax) but simply I want to get an output like that whenever I use `\command1[x]{}`:

- if (x) == 1: output: ABC
- if (x) == 2: output: CBA
- if (x) == 3: output: NNN

Is it possible to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, there are various way, but you can't define a command with a number in it. So use \mycommand or \commandi but not \command1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifnum #1=1 %
    ABC%
  \fi%
  \ifnum #1=2 %
    CBA%
  \fi%
  \ifnum #1=3 %
    NNN%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
test \foo{1}

test \foo{2}

test \foo{3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this approach returns nothing if you pass `\foo{4}`, for example.

Comment: but if I add \ifnum #1=4% then I can also use it for \foo{4} right?

Comment: @OnurGürdoğan, yes.

Comment: Okay that is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: @Sigur Yes. :-) Actually in your special case of a letter (which is not expandable)  following the second number (which would also terminate the scanning for more digits/optional space)  it was already okay before the edit. But now you are safe of unexpected premature expansion in cases where an expandable token follows the second number. Let's remove obsolete comments. ;-)

Comment: Is it necessary to use "[1]" those brackets while defining the \newcommand, before the \ifnum -- \fi statements? I know why we used those brackets but why we put "1" in it? Can it be also "2"? I have tested locally but I did not understand very well..

Comment: @OnurGürdoğan, it indicates that the command you are defining has one argument, that is, should be used as `\foo{<argument here>}`.

Comment: @Sigur, I do not know much about the \newcommand sorry but let's assume we have 2 arguments then how it will be looked.. Arguments referring which statement in this \newcommand structure you proposed?

Comment: @OnurGürdoğan, `\newcommand{\foo}[2]{the 1st argument is #1 and the 2nd one is #2}` and then you can call it as `\foo{this is one}{this is two}`.

Answer (score 7):

If the choices are a consecutive range of numbers, I'd use an `\ifcase` construct:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]
  {%
    \ifcase#1
      Stuff for 0.%
    \or
      Stuff for 1.%
    \or
      Stuff for 2.%
    \else
      Stuff for other cases.%
    \fi
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

And here an expl3 variant, which would work also with something different than numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\mycommand[1]
 { 
   \str_case:nn {#1}
   { 
     {1}{ABC}
     {2}{CBA}
     {3}{NNN}
     {x}{XXX}
   }  
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycommand{1}

\mycommand{2}

\mycommand{3}

\mycommand{x}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When having TeX create tokens by reading and tokenizing characters of a line of a .tex-input-file TeX will only consider characters of category code 11(letter) to be parts of names of control-sequences whose names consist of more than one letter. Digit-characters `0123456789` usually have category code 12(other).

I.e., the sequence of characters (not tokens yet!) `\command1` in the .tex-input will be tokenized as control-word token `\command` followed by an explicit character token whose character code is 49 (49 is the number of the code point of the character `1` in ASCII and in Unicode) and whose category code is 12(other), also denoted as `112`.

Besides having TeX read and tokenize characters of a line of .tex-input there is another way of creating control-sequence tokens: Have TeX evaluate a `\csname..\endcsname`-expression.
E.g. `\csname command1\endcsname` will be tokenized as:

- control-word-token `\csname`
- `c11`
- `o11`
- `m11`
- `m11`
- `a11`
- `n11`
- `d11`
- `112`
- control-word-token `\endcsname`

Expanding the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression yields the control-word-token `\command1`.

I can offer a macro
`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{foo}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\foo`
which does the `\csname..\endcsname`-thingie for you:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
  \@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
    \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
}%
```

If it is ensured that the argument depending on which forking shall take place in any case consists of a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity, you can apply `\number` to it and then use a macro based on delimited arguments for forking the cases—this is the macro based on delimited arguments for forking the cases:

Syntax:

```
\OneTwoThreeElseFork{⟨sequence of digits⟩}%
                    {⟨tokens in case ⟨sequence of digits⟩ = 1⟩}%
                    {⟨tokens in case ⟨sequence of digits⟩ = 2⟩}%
                    {⟨tokens in case ⟨sequence of digits⟩ = 3⟩}%
                    {⟨tokens in case ⟨sequence of digits⟩ = s.th. else⟩}
```

Implementation:

```
\newcommand\OneTwoThreeElseFork[5]{%
  \ExtractOneTwoThreeElseCase!#1!2!3!{#2}% <- in case #1 = 1 deliver #2
                             !1!#1!3!{#3}% <- in case #1 = 2 deliver #3
                             !1!2!#1!{#4}% <- in case #1 = 3 deliver #4
                             !1!2!3!{#5}% <- in case #1 = s.th. else deliver #5
                             !!!!%
}%
\@ifdefinable\ExtractOneTwoThreeElseCase{%
  \long\def\ExtractOneTwoThreeElseCase#1!1!2!3!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
```

Putting the pieces together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\parindent=0ex

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
  \@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
    \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
  %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \newcommand\OneTwoThreeElseFork[5]{%
    \ExtractOneTwoThreeElseCase!#1!2!3!{#2}% <- in case #1 = 1 deliver #2
                               !1!#1!3!{#3}% <- in case #1 = 2 deliver #3
                               !1!2!#1!{#4}% <- in case #1 = 3 deliver #4
                               !1!2!3!{#5}% <- in case #1 = s.th. else deliver #5
                               !!!!%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\ExtractOneTwoThreeElseCase{%
    \long\def\ExtractOneTwoThreeElseCase#1!1!2!3!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
  }%
  %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % Use \CsNameToCsToken to create the control-word-token "\command1" from the sequence "command1":
  \CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{command1}[1]{%
    \expandafter\OneTwoThreeElseFork\expandafter{\number#1}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

% As under normal category code régime you cannot obtain the control-word-token "\command1" 
% directly by having TeX read and tokenize .tex-input, use \CsNameToCsToken to create the
% control-word-token "\command1" from the character sequence "command1":

\verb|\def\one{1 }|\\
\verb|\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{\one}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}|\\
yields:\\
\def\one{1 }
\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{\one}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{1}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}|\\
yields:\\
\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{1}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{2}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}|\\
yields:\\
\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{2}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{3}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}|\\
yields:\\
\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{3}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{23}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}|\\
yields:\\
\CsNameToCsToken{command1}{23}{Case 1}{Case 2}{Case 3}{Some other case}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As `\OneTwoThreeElseFork` does without any `\if..\fi`-constructs, **`\OneTwoThreeElseFork` does not "explode" in case** you wish `\OneTwoThreeElseFork` to deliver some **unbalanced `\if..` or `\else` or `\or` or `\fi`**.

However it is just relied on the first argument of `\command1` being a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.

There is no checking/error-catching implemented on that because strictly spoken this is not possible:

At the time of expanding them, the tokens forming the first argument of `\command1` may form an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm. Having an algorithm check whether such an algorithm in the end yields a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity implies having an algorithm check whether an other arbitrary algorithm  terminates at all/terminates without error-messages. This is the halting-problem. Alan Turing proved that it is not possible to implement an algorithm which for any arbitrary algorithm can "decide" whether that other algorithm will ever terminate.

Comment: @Skillmon  Thank you for removing the erroneous hash. ;-)

Comment: You're welcome! It was an interesting read (though it might be overkill) :)

Comment: @Skillmon Sometimes I am carried away by the ambition of securing things against -eh- malicious user input. ;-)

Comment: I think one could implement a check whether the first argument to `\command1` will throw an error in `\number` or not (the only uncatched issue would then be if it results in an infinite loop, so still not a complete solution to the halting-problem).

Comment: @Skillmon On April 1st somebody might offer some bounty for *completely* solving the halting-problem in TeX *only by expansion-methods*.  ;-)

Comment: @Skillmon There might be surprising behavior without throwing an error.  E.g., how to handle the situation of `1<space token>23` being passed to `\number`?  This will be turned to `123`.  Should it be considered valid as 1st argument of `\command1`?

Comment: It is only about expandably checking whether `\number` will throw an error or not. Since `\number` will ignore leading spaces (and spaces after signs) anyway, we can just `\romannumeral\`\^^@` expand once, grab the first token and check whether that's a digit, if so, pass the complete result of the expansion to `\number`, else pass some fallback value that'll trigger the else-case. If the first token is a `+` or `-` keep it for reinsertion and redo the check.

Comment: @Skillmon Things like `\number\count4 ` also work out. Checking whether  the result of ```\romannumeral`\^^@\count4 ``` has a first token that is a digit yields that it doesn't because the first token of that result is `\count`.  Similar with alphabetic constants and `\countdef`-tokens etc.

Comment: @Skillmon I don't know if I got the gist of your idea right. (If I got it right, ```\romannumeral`\^^@``` is to be used for removing leading spaces from the expansion of the argument.) With `\def\foobar{\romannumeral\relax}` the sequence ```\romannumeral`\^^@\foobar``` will raise an error even before something like a 1st token of the result is there...

Comment: Didn't consider what happens if the input itself necessarily produces an error...

Answer (score 3):

The `\def` primitive was not menioned in other answers here.

```
\def\command#1{\ifcase#1\or ABC\or CBA\or NNN\fi}

\command1 % outputs ABC
\command2 % outputs CBA
\command3 % outputs NNN

\bye
```

Comment: I don't know if this is about `\def` so much as using `\ifcase`.

Comment: I think @wipet is comparing the \newcommand and \def functions here.

Comment: `\def` in mentioned in the title of this thread but not answered in other answers here.